# Discord.py with bots, are bot commands private to users? How to make them private?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, discord, discord.py

I have a bot that I control with Discord.py - can a user somehow see all the commands that the bot has available? If so, how do I prevent this?

I ask because I have certain commands that I want to be "rewards" but I don't want people to know what they are ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the default help command shows all the commands you have. If you disabled it like this, you should be fine (or if you made your own help command):

```
client.remove_command("help")
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't implement some function that returns all the functions the bot has and prints them to a channel, no one without the source code can see them.
Just make sure to name your functions accordingly so they're not easily guessable.

If you really need a function that lists all available functions you could check if that user is you and if not just do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to remove the help command.

```
bot.remove_command("help")
```

You can remake the help command with this.

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('commands')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the default help command when giving the bot his prefix:

`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', help_command=None)`

and then you can set up your own help command (if you want)